# How to Unset title ('Search results') on Search results page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

How to Unset title ('Search results') on Search results page?

I'm still noobish and I was trying this:

```
function mymodulename_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) 

{
  $variables['title'] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change it with a preprocess since the sentence is just a printed string in the template not a variable. So you have to alter the template.

In the templates folder of your theme, duplicate the template from /root directory of your site/modules/search/search-results.tpl.php.

And edit this file as you wish.

The theme template file will be automatically called instead of the one in the core.

Comment: When you want to your theme call different template file you need to clear the cache always. Like this it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change output rendering. Easy way to do this is to change search core module template file.

Go on:

```
\modules\search\search-results.tpl.php
```

In that file just delete output string or replace it with empty one. Find next line in code:

```
  <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
```

You can delete whole row there or you can change it to:

```
  <h2><?php print t('');?></h2>
```

**NOTE:**
When you change core modules you should pay attention you don't overwrite it with release which comes in new Drupal core (in case you want to upgrade your Drupal core).

If you not sure you will replace this file in future (during possible module or even entire Drupal core update) you might consider copy this file in your theme template folder. After putting that file in your theme template files folder you just need to clear the cache and that file will be called instead of one in core module.

@Laurent Thank you for your update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a good idea, you are modifying core files to do something that can be done in many others ways (with a custom template for example). Next time you decide to upgrade your core because of a security issue, if you did many of these changes it will be a lot of time wasted reapplying them.

Comment: It's a good point. I will add note for that. But really, he asked such a trivial question and you hope he will know to do core upgrade...Also when you upgrade core for security reason you read log first to know what is changed. If core module you changed is modified you will for sure know what file you need to back up during upgrade... It is also very bad practice to overwrite all core files during core update because you need to test it first. Many if there but ok... Point taken, it is not a good practice to change core module if you know that in future you might overwrite it.